# Mysql before delete trigger, prevent delete if no where clause?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know there's no "NEW" value in a delete trigger, so not sure if this is possible. I am trying to use a before delete trigger to log some values, which works fine, except I'd also like to prevent the deletion of any records if the user does not specify anything in the where clause.  Basically, I don't want them wiping out the whole table.  (app devs with code mistakes actually)

Currently I have:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger tg_order_shipping_bd
before delete on order_shipping
FOR EACH ROW
begin

        insert into order_shipping_log
        (log_type, inv_nbr, old_tracking_nbr)
        values ( 'DEL', OLD.inv_nbr, OLD.tracking_nbr);

end
$$
```

So is there a clever way to count rows affected, and if more than 1, prevent delete and error?  Maybe just rethinking how we handle this is better. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's really a mistake a developer should only make once... but, here's the correct fix if you believe it needs to be system-wide.  No cleverness required.  (Also, triggers in MySQL are `FOR EACH ROW` so the answer to your question is "not really" although you could hack it with clever use of a session variable or two).

MySQL has a system variable called [sql_safe_updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates).

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_safe_updates = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Disconnect and reconnect so your session picks up the new global value.

```
mysql> delete from t1;
ERROR 1175 (HY000): You are using safe update mode and you tried to update
                    a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
```

When using the command line client, you can temporarily enable this setting just for your session with this flag:

```
$ mysql --i-am-a-dummy
```

(No, I'm not making this up).

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know that one! I'll work with that in mind.  And yes, its not likely to happen and we are always careful, but doesn't take much to mess up unknowingly if not checking variables. I usually flag records as deleted and use a view, or sproc, or check for value first on important tables.  What also might work in this particular case is to update to NULL and not do deletes in code.  That's a cool idea though using safe updates! Thanks so much for the input!

Comment: Also, on the topic of unintended deletions, here's a free tip... if you have binary logging enabled and `binlog_format` set to `row`, when rows are deleted, the binary log actually contains all of the column values from each deleted row.  In an emergency, you can parse the output of `mysqlbinlog` and reconstruct what you lost.  Depending on the storage engine and other settings, this can also be true sometimes if `binlog_format` is set to `mixed`.